# TypeSctipt/vsc ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED auto import problem

Tags: javascript, typescript

When I make auto import `vsc` import int with full path like this

```
import { MetadataStorage } from "discordx/build/cjs/logic/index.js";
```

The correct import would be like this.

```
import { MetadataStorage } from "discordx";
```

And when I run the code, it gives me this error:

```
 Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath 
./build/esm/logic/index.js' is not defined by "exports" in 
E:\Coding\GitHub Reps\RP-Community-Bot\node_modules\discordx\package.json


imported from E:\Coding\GitHub Reps\RP-Community-Bot\build\index.js
```

Everything was fine before.

But today, after launching `vsc`, there was such a problem.

When I manually change everything starts working again.

But of course, this is not a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. The second time I tried reinstalling npm and restarting vsc. And this time it solved my problem